# How to place expl3 function output to variable not in stream?

Tags: expl3, programming, latex3

As explained in `interface3`

> `\int_to_roman:n {<integer expression>}`
>
> Places the value of the `<integer expression>` in the input stream as Roman numerals, either lower case (`\int_to_roman:n`) or upper case `\int_to_Roman:n`). The Roman numerals are letters with category code 11 (letter).

But, how can I put function value into a some variable, say `\l_here_str` not in stream (If I correctly understand stream mean "output to `LaTeX` document")?

Maybe the more general question, that refer to the behavior of conventional programming languages, where the functions values can be assigned to the variables: how does it implemented in `expl3`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_roman:n {V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_roman:n {V}


\NewDocumentCommand{\CharCount}{ m }
{   \tl_set:Nn \l_roman_tl {#1}
    \int_to_roman:V \l_roman_tl % How to assign mmciv to some variable, say \l_here_str
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent\CharCount{2104}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_set:Nx \l_sk_roman_tl { \int_to_roman:n { #1 } }`? (With a previous declaration outside of the function `\tl_new:N \l_sk_roman_tl`, don't forget that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately `expl3` is written in TeX so retains the fundamental of being a macro expansion language. Here, if you want to store the *outcome* of a function rather than the exact input you need to force evaluation. That is normally done by what is known as `x`-type expansion

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \int_to_roman:n {#1} } % _Exactly_ "\int_to_roman:n {#1}"
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \int_to_roman:n {#1} } % Result of \int_to_roman:n
```

This will work with any expandable function (those marked with a star in `interface3`).

If you were producing an integer here you would probably use an `int` variable. These *can only hold integers* so *automatically* evaluate their argument to yield one. For example, for the reverse conversion:

```
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_from_roman:n {#1} }
```

---

One note if you have a 'classical' programming background: the `str` type is rather specialised in TeX, and `tl` is much more generally used. TeX associates a 'category code' with every token, and this affects interpretation. Most of the time you want to retain that meaning, so a `tl` is the way to go. (The `str` type is a special case of `tl` in which all characters are 'other', except for spaces which are 'space'.)